# Create directory extension property Microsoft graph Api: Java

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api

I want to create directory extension properties for my application from Java SDK. I have installed all required packages and libraries.

I used same sample code given in docs :

```java
GraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder().authenticationProvider( authProvider ).buildClient();

ExtensionProperty extensionProperty = new ExtensionProperty();
extensionProperty.name = "jobGroup";
extensionProperty.dataType = "String";
LinkedList<String> targetObjectsList = new LinkedList<String>();
targetObjectsList.add("User");
extensionProperty.targetObjects = targetObjectsList;

graphClient.applications("fd918e4b-c821-4efb-b50a-5eddd23afc6f").extensionProperties()
    .buildRequest()
    .post(extensionProperty);
```

Throwing errors like `401 Unauthorized` while executing. How to solve my issue?

Have consent for `Application.ReadWrite.All` permission in my application. What else may be causing the issue?

Any help is much needed

Comment: If you used sample code from the docs you need to set the correct application id and you are using application permission type (not delegated) you need consent for Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy permission

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the application permissions then you need to add another permission here that is "Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy".

Here are the permissions required for Create extension Property:

[image]

For more information:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-extensionproperty?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions

Hope this helps.